# 'TypeError: req.flash is not a function' with app.use(flash()); and still not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

The error occrus on my routes.js:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
    res.render('login.html', { message:  req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
});
```

On the `req.flash` to be more specific.

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//PASSPORT AUTH
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

As you can see I have `app.use(flash())`; which was the most common error on the other cases.

Flash is initialized at the beginning as such:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
```

I really don't see where the problem is.

EDIT: ERROR PAGE:

[image: error]

Comment: I added the pic of the error and realized aswell the problem is NOT on the get method but rather, as it says in the pic somewhere else (maybe in the module). There is a problem with the req.flash in the GET though, as the GET form only shows when I take it out.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Did you try to create a minimal test case? Your problem is probably somewhere else in the code. Maybe app.use(flash()) is not being run?

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')
var app = express();

app.use(flash());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }))

app.get('/flash', function(req, res){
  req.flash('info', 'Flash is back!')
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send(req.flash('info'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I literally replaced my app.js with that and it worked. Both messages appeared as they should... Don't know why upon logging in it doesn't...

Comment: Please check my edit for a pic of the actual error as it seems to go deeper.

Comment: Make sure order of session comes before any routes